# Trying to iterate through .wav files in a directory (Python)

Tags: python, loops, operating-system, wav, pydub

I'm trying to iterate through a directory that contains a list of wav files as shown below:

[image]

My goal is to go through each wav file and add it to a wav file called transcript.wav which is located inside its parent directory.

For example, the output I'm hoping to get is that for every chunk there is a corresponding "new_audio" file with the correct number. So *"chunk0.wav"* becomes *"new_audio0.wav"*, *"chunk1.wav"* becomes *"new_audio1.wav"* and so on.

**Here is my code:**

```
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

directory = "C:/Users/Nahuel/Workfiles/audio_chunks"

for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".wav"):
        p1 = AudioSegment.from_wav(filename)
        p2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("C:/Users/Nahuel/Workfiles/transcript.wav")
        newAudio = p1 + p2
        newAudio.export('new_audio.wav', format="wav")
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

**This is the error** I get. It says that file 'chunk0.wav' is not found. But it is there in the directory so I am left scratching my head.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're just not running your code in the wav directory. `listdir` just return the filename, not the whole path, you need to join with the directory

```
p1 = AudioSegment.from_wav(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

Comment: @NahuelMel You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use an absolute path for your `filename`, depending on where your Python program is stored. You should use:

```
filename = os.path.join(directory, file)
```

instead of:

```
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
```

Side note, check your indentation in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` package and `os.path.join()` to help. This code removes some of those checks for `.wav` files as well because you can explicitly search for those using the `glob.glob()` function.

```py
import os
import glob
from pydub import AudioSegment

directory = os.path.join('c:/', 'Users', 'Nahuel', 'Workfiles')

for file in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, 'audio_chunks', '*.wav'))):
    p1 = AudioSegment.from_wav(file)
    p2 = AudioSegment.from_wav(os.path.join(directory, 'transcript.wav')
    newAudio = p1 + p2
    newAudio.export('new_audio.wav', format="wav")
```